# Car Rental Form

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Car Rental Calculator</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">  
    .number { font-weight: bold; } 
     </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php // Script 4.2 - handle_calc.php
    /* This script takes values from calculator.html and performs 
    total cost and monthly payment calculations. */

    // Address error handling, if you want.
    if(isset($_POST['f_name'])){
    // Get the values from the $_POST array:
    $Name = $_POST['f_name'];
    $depositAmount = $_POST['deposit'];
    $days = $_POST['days'];
    $B_miles = $_POST['b_mileage'];
    $E_miles = $_POST['e_mileage'];
    $insurance = $_POST['insurance'];
    $drivers = $_POST['drivers'];
    $car = $_POST['rental'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $gas = $_POST['gas'];

    // Calculate the total:
    switch ($car) {
    case "subcompact":
       $car_per_day = 20;
        $max_gas_gallons = 10;
        break;

    case "compact":
       $car_per_day = 30;
        $max_gas_gallons = 20;
        break;

    case "luxury":
       $car_per_day = 40;
        $max_gas_gallons = 30;
        break;

    case "mid-size":
       $car_per_day = 25;
        $max_gas_gallons = 35;
        break;

    case "minivan":
       $car_per_day = 80;
        $max_gas_gallons = 20;
        break;

    case "suv":
       $car_per_day = 60;
        $max_gas_gallons = 15;
        break;
}



    if (isset($_POST['drivers_under_25'])) {
   $drivers_under_25 = $_POST['drivers_under_25'];
    }
    else {
    $drivers_under_25 = 0;  
    }
if ($_POST['gas'] == 'empty' { price = xx} else { price =zz }

    $daycharge = 30.00 * $days;
    $initial_amount = $daycharge + .35 *($E_miles - $B_miles - ($days * 100) );
    $initial_amount = $initial_amount - $depositAmount;

    $gas_charge = ($max_gas_gallons - $gallons_user) *$price_per_gallon;

    $drivercharge = 5 *($drivers - 1);

    $initial_amount = $initial_amount + $drivercharge;

    $inscharge = $initial_amount * $insurance;

    $total = $initial_amount + $inscharge;
     // Print out the results:
    echo 'Hello ';
    echo $Name;
    echo "<br>";

    echo 'Deposit Amount : ' ;
    echo $depositAmount;
    echo "<br>";

    echo 'Your daily charge will be: ';
    echo $daycharge;
    echo "<br>";


    echo 'Total Days : ';
    echo $days;
    echo "<br>";

    echo 'Insurance Charge : ';
    echo  $inscharge;
    echo "<br>";

    echo 'Driver Charge : ';
    echo $drivercharge;
    echo "<br>";


    echo 'Your Total Price : ';
    echo $total;
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain what your code is doing, please.

Comment: this is a code for a car rental form, would like me to share my html part too @SimonAndréForsberg

Comment: I think @SimonAndréForsberg means for you to edit the title of your question so it is more relevant to what your code does.

Comment: What exactly are you unsure about that requires review?

Comment: And some more text in the question to summarize the code would be a good idea.

Comment: i just want to know what everyone thinks of my code, and if it needs work

Comment: @Garry General code reviews [are accepted](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/790/should-a-post-with-no-specific-questions-imply-a-general-review) on Code Review. Doesn't need to be anything.

Comment: You will want to sanitize all of those strings before you write them out; otherwise there's an XSS risk to your application.

Answer (score 3):

Just a few things (not including the obvious suggestion to try an object-oriented implementation - though I prefer it, a script of this size won't hurt anyone this way):

1. Your `switch()` statement doesn't have a `default:` case.  What
   happens if there's a problem with the input and it doesn't match any
   case?  This *can* be a security risk.
2. Have you considered simply setting the values of your calculations
   in this script and then `return`ing them?  This will allow your end user to do whatever   they like with the HTML and place your variables where they're necessary rather than tying your front-end design to your function.
3. You really need to name your variables more consistently and meaningfully.  It seems like a small thing, but will make all the difference in the long run.  Start this practice now with small applications and you'll continue it when you work on the big stuff - and it'll pay off.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's always a good practise to put all your PHP logic above the template (or in another file) and only put some simple if statements and echo in the HTML itself. This avoids "headers already send" errors and it's better for seperation of the code.

**Line 19-28.** Here you simply save the POST variables in variables. This is just useless spilling of memory, why don't you use the POST variables instead?
**Line 17.** You can better check if the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is POST
**Line 71.** Syntax error, you are missing `)` and `price` is not a variable (missing `$`) and `xx` and `zz` are not strings: `if ($_POST['gas'] == 'empty' { price = xx} else { price =zz }`

Some overall tips:

- Please be consistent, choose a coding standard and use it everywhere in your script. Make sure you indents are the same everywhere, your variables all use the same capitialization rules, etc.
- Including an input, e.g. `f_name`, only to be able to show his name seems a bit weird to me. I'd like to only input things the application needs, instead of some stuff to personalize the final message...
- Break you code into functions. This way you can easily call `calculateCarRental(...)` and it'll give you the information.
- Use validation. You don't check if the user filled in the fields.

Comment: Saving the POST variables to other variables is *ugly* - I'll give you that. But arguing that it's "spilling of memory" is kinda pointless. Variables are cheap, and you have no idea if PHP will alias those variables together (which it will if you Zend optimise it). Even if they don't get aliased, variables are cheap and will cost a trivial quantity of memory compared with, say, doing a single concatenation operation anywhere in the program.

Comment: Comments are even cheaper than variables. More `$_POST` variables like, `$gas` and `$age`, are saved into other variables than are later used in the code. A comment telling the next programmer which form fields are available would be cheaper than just rote copying of all `$_POST` variables.